# What is the real radius of capillary tube?

Tags: physics

> You have a capillary tube in a capsule whose refractive index is $n = 2$. You notice that the radius of capillary tube seems $1.50mm$. What is the real radius of capillary tube?

I'm having trouble with this optics question.

Let's take a look at what we have:

Refractive index of capsule: $n = 2$

Radius of capillary tube: $1.50mm$

Refractive index of air: $n = 1$

Can I get your thinkings?

Comment: Any idea? It's not that hard to comment on it.

Comment: got any  picture?

Comment: @orangeskid I wish I got.

Comment: I still didn't get the problem.

Comment: Can't anyone take a look at the question?